# Retrieving data through LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, web-applications

I got a weird problem here like I got a site that users can post comments on a friend profile page.Everytime a user post a comment my application sends e-mail to that page owner, you know to inform for a new posted comment on his/her profile page.The problem is I want to stop the application from sending email if that user has just recently posted a comment say like 5 hours ago/earlier.Here is the function I use that would try to check it:

```
Public Function CheckForNewPost(ByVal arg As String) As Boolean

        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Using dc As New WhatEverDataContext()
            Dim newcomment = From mytable In dc.PostTable _
                           Where mytable.PostingUser.ToLower() = User.Identity.Name.ToLower() And mytable.PageOwner.ToLower() = arg.ToLower() And mytable.PostedDate.AddHours(5) >= DateTime.Now _
                           Select mytable
            For Each comment In newcomment
                x = x + 1
            Next
            If x > 0 Then
         'user has posted a comment recently
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    End Function
```

Then I use it like this:

```
  Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemInserted
        'send our mail
        Dim PageOwner As String = Request.QueryString.Get("PageOwnerName")
        If CheckForNewPost(PageOwner) = False Then
            SendEMail(PageOwner)
        End If

    End Sub
```

But still the app still sending the mail even the user just posted 5 hours earlier.
What do you think I'm doing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be clearer if you write your condition as

```
mytable.PostedDate <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5)
```

as the right hand side now reads as "Five Hours Ago."

So the entire condition now reads as *My posted date is earlier than (or equal to) five hours ago.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking to see if mytable.PostedDate.AddHours(5) <= DateTime.Now. I think you just got it backwards.

```
mytable.PostedDate.AddHours(5) <= DateTime.Now
```